# Given $\sinh x$, find the exact value of $\cosh x, \cos 2x$ and $\tan 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Given $\sinh x = 8/14$, find the exact value of $\cosh x, \cos 2x$ and $\tan 2x$.

I have been getting two answers which has made me confused. I keep getting $\sqrt{65/7}$ or $\sqrt{4/7}.$

That's what I got:  $$\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$$ $$\cosh^2 x = 1 + \sinh^2 x$$ $$\cosh^2 x = 1 +\left(\frac{8}{14}\right)^2$$ $$\cosh^2 x=\frac{65}{49}$$ $$\cosh (x) = \sqrt{\frac{65}{49}}$$ $$\cosh x = \frac{\sqrt{65}}{7}$$

Comment: Show your work @kayla

Comment: Some useful identities are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions

Comment: With $\sinh x = 8/14 = 4/7,$ then yes, $\cosh x = \frac{\sqrt{65}}{7}.$

Comment: Please do not delete the context of your question. Context is essential for understanding your question and the answers that depend on it.

Comment: @Kayla Do you want to ask a new question for the parts $\cos 2x$ and $\tan 2x$? This part of the question has nothing to do with hyperbolic functions and thus would be better off as its own question? As always, please show the same working out as you have shown here.

Comment: @Kayla Please also accept one of the answers if you find any of them useful. It has been 5 days since you asked this question, which has been since closed, so there are not going to be any new answers. You can accept by clicking the grey tick which will turn it green.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sinh x =\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}= \frac{4}{7}$$
We want
$$\cosh x = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} = q$$
Adding these:
$$e^x = \frac{4}{7}+q$$
Subtracting the first equation from the second:
$$e^{-x} = q - \frac{4}{7}$$
So $$\frac{4}{7}+q = \frac{1}{q-\frac{4}{7}}$$
$$q^2 - \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2 =1$$
$$q^2 =1+\frac{16}{49}$$
$$\cosh x = q=\frac{\sqrt{65}}{7}$$(q must be positive because each exponential is positive.)

Answer (score 1):

You are right!  Just use $$\cosh^2 x = 1+\sinh^2 x.$$

Now it only amounts to keeping track of what $\sinh x$ is and carefully doing the calculation.  Is it $\sinh^2 x  = \left(\frac{8}{13}\right)^2$ or is it $\sinh^2 x  = \left(\frac{8}{14}\right)^2$?

UPDATE:  With $\sinh x = \frac{4}{7}$:

$$\cosh^2 x = 1+ \left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^2 = 1+ \frac{16}{49}$$
so
$$\cosh x = \frac{\sqrt{65}}{7}.$$

Comment: Yeah sinh^2 x = 8/14 sorry

Comment: Okay, so we'll stay with $\sinh x = \frac{8}{14} = \frac{4}{7}.$  That's what you mean, yes.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cosh^2 x = 1 + \sinh^2 x.$$
error was here
$$\rightarrow \cosh^2 x = 1 +(8/13)^2.$$
$$\cosh^2 x=(233/169).$$
$$\cosh (x) = \sqrt {233}/13.$$